# Not Inefficient Way Of Returning Object In Array With Maximum Value Of Certain Property?

Tags: javascript

I feel that this is repetitive and/or inefficient:

```
self.get_max_dist = function(array) {

    var arr = array.map(function(value) {
        return value.distance;
    });

    var max = Math.max.apply(null, arr);

    return array.filter(function(el) {
        return el.distance === max;
    });

};
```

How do I remove my feeling?

Sample array:

```
[
    {
        distance: 256.62,
        maxspeed: 340.65,
        pid: "675",
        prestrafe: 275.626
    },

    ...

]
```

Comment: ... and the question is?

Comment: You need to describe "efficient". Is it speed, terseness, readability...

Comment: not repetitive, so terseness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execution efficiency will probably come by making one pass through the array rather than the three passes in your code.  Here's a one pass solution:

```
self.get_max_dist = function(array) {
    var output = [], max = 0, item;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        item = array[i];
        if (item.distance > max) {
            // new max value so initialize
            // output starting with this item
            output = [item];
            max = item.distance;
        } else if (item.distance === max) {
            // found another item with our max value
            // so add it to the current output
            output.push(item);
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

For simplicity of coding, this makes an assumption that distances are not negative.  If you don't want that assumption, a few more lines of code could be added to deal with that.

---

If you're only looking to get a single max distance item, you can do that a bit simpler:

```
self.get_max_dist = function(array) {
    var max, item;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        item = array[i];
        if (!max || (item.distance > max.distance)) {
            max = item;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

---

Or, if you like iterators, this last one can be:

```
self.get_max_dist = function(array) {
    var max;
    array.foreach(function(item) {
        if (!max || (item.distance > max.distance)) {
            max = item;
        }
    });
    return max;
}
```

Comment: props for taking into account the possibility of distances having equal values, however this version of the function does not return a correct object when i test it and i can't find anything wrong about the code. the second version works beautifully though!

Comment: @tenub - Do you realize that the first version returns an array?  Also, I added another flavor of the second one.

Comment: yes i do. i'm not a javascript novice. the object from the array is not the same. `[ { block: 256, distance: 257.376, maxspeed: 343, name: "round", prestrafe: 275.74 } ]` !== `{ name: "DeathClaw", block: 257, distance: 258.027, prestrafe: 275.238, maxspeed: 343.053 }`. from my other data set: `[ {distance: 215.002, maxspeed: 280.909, pid: "6532", prestrafe: 267.313 } ]` !== `{ pid: "675", distance: 256.62, maxspeed: 340.65, prestrafe: 275.626 }`. the result seems to be the last object in each array.